# Why can't coq infer the that 0+n=n in this dependently typed program?

Tags: list, type-inference, coq, dependent-type

I'm starting to use Coq and I'd like to define some dependently typed programs. Consider the following:

```
Inductive natlist : nat -> Type :=
  | natnil : natlist 0
  | natcons : forall k, nat -> natlist k -> natlist (S k).

Fixpoint natappend (n:nat) (l1: natlist n) (m:nat) (l2: natlist m) : natlist (n+m) :=
  match l1 with
    | natnil => l2
    | natcons _ x rest => natcons (n+m) x (natappend rest l2)
  end.
```

So `natlist k` would be a list of `nat`s of length `k`. The problem with the definition of concatenation as `natappend` is the following error:

```
Error:
In environment
natappend : forall n : nat,
            natlist n ->
            forall m : nat,
            natlist m -> natlist (n + m)
n : nat
l1 : natlist n
m : nat
l2 : natlist m
The term "l2" has type "natlist m"
while it is expected to have type
 "natlist (?n@{n1:=0} + m)".
```

As you can see it has a problem with the clause:

```
| natnil => l2
```

because it claims that the type of `l2` is `natlist m` while the result type must be `natlist (n+m) = natlist (0+m)`.

I know that Coq cannot resolve arbitrary expressions at the type level to avoid non-terminating computations, but I find strange that even this simple case isn't handled.

I'm running CoqIDE on linux, the version is:

```
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.5 (February 2016)
  compiled on Feb 22 2016 18:19:5 with OCaml 4.02.2
```

I've seen live classes using the MacOSX version with code similar to the above that compiled in the IDE without that error, so I'm a bit puzzled.

Is there some setting that I have to set to enable more type inference and allow the kind of code as above? Alternatively: how can I write dependently typed code that doesn't rely on type inference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you had a type error in your second branch. Here is a version that works:

```
Fixpoint natappend {n m:nat} (l1 : natlist n) (l2 : natlist m) : natlist (n + m) :=
  match l1 with
  | natnil => l2
  | natcons n' x rest => natcons (n' + m) x (natappend rest l2)
  end.
```

The crucial difference between this version and the original one is the parameter passed to `natcons`: here, it is `n' + m`, whereas before it was `n + m`.

This example illustrates very well a general issue with non-locality of error messages in Coq, in particular when writing dependently typed programs. Even though Coq complained about the first branch, the problem was actually in the second branch. Adding annotations in your `match` statement, as suggested by @jbapple, can be useful when trying to diagnose what is going wrong.

Comment: I had no idea that there could be this kind of issue. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You need `match ... as ... in ... return ...` to do more sophisticated type annotations. See [Adam Chlipala's chapter "Library MoreDep" in his Book "Certified Programming with Dependent Types"](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html) or ["Chapter 17: Extended pattern-matching" in the Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual020.html). Both have the `concat` example you are working on.

You could also just delay the dependent type bit until the end:

```
Definition natlist n := { x : list nat & n = length x }.
```

Then prove that non-dependently-typed `concat` preserves length sums.

Comment: But then can you tell me why my professor doesn't need the `in ... return`? I'm following a Logical Frameworks course where we use Coq and, AFAIK, he is using the same version as me but the `concat` example he wrote *live during class* didn't need anything fancy and compiled without troubles.

Comment: My version needs the annotations, too, so I'm not sure. However, it probably doesn't help that your first argument to natcons is too much: `natcons k` produces something of type `natlist (S k)`. Your constructor in the second branch has `k = n+m`, so the result will be of type `natlist (S (n+m))`, which is not what you want.

Comment: I much support @jbapple 's definition of natlist as a dependent record instead of the original one, however I'd suggest using `Definition natlist n := { x : list nat & n == length x }.` where `==` is the boolean equality on nat, for reasons of proof irrelevance.

Comment: @ejgallego How does that make it proof irrelevant?

Comment: In general using a bool makes it easier to prove injectivity of the first projection, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290012/inductive-subset-of-an-inductive-set-in-coq/35300521#35300521

Comment: By the way, I learned about this by reading the tuple.v , a very good example of a complete sized list library is http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/mathcomp.ssreflect.tuple.html , I really learned a lot from trying to understand it.