# Best way to handle (sub) types of the form `{ x : nat | x >= 13 /\ x <= 19 }`?

Tags: coq

**Coq** would let me define this :

```
Definition teenagers : Set := { x : nat | x >= 13 /\ x <= 19 }.
```

and also :

```
Variable Julia:teenagers.
```

but not :

```
Example minus_20 : forall x:teenagers, x<20.
```

or :

```
Example Julia_fact1 : Julia > 12.
```

This is because Julia (of type *teenagers*) cannot be compared to 12 (*nat*).

**Q:** How should I inform Coq that Julia's support type is *nat* so that I can write anything useful about her ?

**Q':** My definition of teenagers seems like a dead end ; it is more declarative than constructive and I seem to have lost inductive properties of *nat*. How can I show up its inhabitants ? If there is no way, I can still stick to *nat* and work with *Prop* and functions. (newbie here, less than one week self learning with [Pierce's SF](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you are using in `teenagers` is an instance of the "subType" pattern. As you have noted, a `{ x : nat | P x }` is different from `nat`. Currently, Coq provides little support to handle these kind of types effectively, but if you restrict to "well-behaved" classes of `P`, you can actually work in a reasonable way. [This should really become a Coq FAQ BTW]

In the long term, you may want to use special support for this pattern. A good example of such support is provided by the math-comp library `subType` interface.

Describing this interface is beyond your original question, so I will end with a few comments:

- In your `minus_20` example, you want to use the *first projection* of your teenagers datatype. Try `forall x : teenagers, proj1_sig x < 20`. Coq can try to insert such projection automatically if you declare the projection as a `Coercion`:

  ```
  Require Import Omega.

  Definition teenagers : Set :=
    { x : nat | x >= 13 /\ x <= 19 }.

  Coercion teen_to_nat := fun x : teenagers => proj1_sig x.

  Implicit Type t : teenagers.

  Lemma u t : t < 20.
  Proof. now destruct t; simpl; omega. Qed.
  ```
- As you have correctly observed, `{ x : T | P x }` is not the same in Coq than `x`. In principle, you cannot transfer reasoning from objects of type `T` to objects of type `{ x : T | P x }` as you must also reason in addition about objects of type `P x`. But for a wide class of `P`, you can show that the `teen_to_nat` projection is injective, that is:

  ```
  forall t1 t2, teen_to_nat t1 = teen_to_nat t2 -> t1 = t2.
  ```

  Then, reasoning over the base type can be transferred to the subtype. See also: [Inductive subset of an inductive set in Coq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290012/inductive-subset-of-an-inductive-set-in-coq/35300521#35300521)

**[edit]:** I've added a couple typical examples of subTypes in math-comp, as I think they illustrate well the concept:

- Sized lists or `n.-tuples`. A list of length n is represented in math-comp as a pair of a single list plus a proof of size, that is to say `n.-tuple T = { s : seq T | size s == n}`. Thanks to injectivity and coertions, you can use all the regular list functions over tuples and they work fine.
- Bounded natural or ordinals: similarly, the type `'I_n = { x : nat | x < n }` works almost the same than a natural number, but with a bound.

Comment: Thx ! That's already a lot of new keywords (Coercion ?) and concepts for me but I am glad that there is a positive answer to dig in. Thx also for being so active & constructive on coq tag.

Comment: You are welcome; this particular use case is a complicated one specially for beginners and IIRC not covered in-depth in SF. Feel free to ask any question you have about the code.

Comment: @FZed CPDT covers subset types, starting from [this chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.Subset.html).

Comment: @AntonTrunov I'm much afraid that for most purposes, I'd recommend using the math-comp infrastructure over the CPDT proposed one, that being said, indeed an excellent read.

Comment: I wish there was a textbook on math-comp/ssreflect I could recommend :)

Comment: I heard something is on the works... There will be a tutorial soon at ITP soon thou: https://github.com/math-comp/wiki/wiki/tutorial-itp2016 which can be run in the browser, also this provides some exercises https://team.inria.fr/marelle/en/advanced-coq-winter-school-2016/ but it is geared towards math.